# LayoutSubviews during animation causes "pending changes" messages in Xcode 8.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch

During a `UIView` animation, `layoutSubviews` is called on a child view. Within that call to `layoutSubviews` I make changes to some existing layers on that view (updates to height and spacing).

```
aSublayer.frame = CGRect(x: (Double(i) * benchWidth), y: 0.0, width: benchWidth, height: currentHeight)
```

During these updates (for each layer that is updated) Xcode outputs a message like below.

```
pending: lineWidth from 1 to Optional(2)
pending: path from <CGPath 0x6000002260c0> to Optional(<CGPath 0x6080002273c0>)
pending: position from NSPoint: {126.45161290322581, 12.5} to Optional(NSPoint: {443.87096774193549, 63})
pending: bounds from NSRect: {{0, 0}, {245, 25}} to Optional(NSRect: {{0, 0}, {860, 126}})
pending: position from NSPoint: {3.9516129032258065, 19.61345452990809} to Optional(NSPoint: {13.870967741935484, 98.851810830736767})
pending: bounds from NSRect: {{0, 0}, {7.903225806451613, 10.773090940183822}} to Optional(NSRect: {{0, 0}, {27.741935483870968, 54.296378338526466}})
pending: position from NSPoint: {3.9516129032258065, 15.226909059816178} to Optional(NSPoint: {13.870967741935484, 72.703621661473534})
pending: bounds from NSRect: {{0, 0}, {7.903225806451613, 2}} to Optional(NSRect: {{0, 0}, {27.741935483870968, 2}})
```

I haven't been able to find any documentation/StackOverflow answers with these messages. My guess is I am making an update to a layer's bounds/frame/etc... and it still has pending changes? I have no way to verify that. From what I can tell, `CALayer` doesn't have any flag as if there are pending changes.

Has anyone seen these messages as well, how do I stop/prevent them, and should this be of any concern? The animation is perfectly performant.

Comment: Were you seeing this in Xcode 7? If you disable OS_ACTIVITY_MODE, would these messages go away?

Comment: @dfd Using Xcode 8.1. Disabled OS_ACTIVITY_MODE and still see the messages.

Comment: It was a thought. While I think I know what you are doing, could you post a bit more code? The animation **call** in particular, but maybe even the full animation code (both main view and subviews). It might help. Also, if I understand you, the animation is working as you intended. Does it work on a device - and if so, is it giving out these messages?